# Using cryptopp-cmake and crypto++ together a CMakeLists.txt project file

Tags: c++, cmake, crypto++

I'm using **Clion** and I'm trying to use [cryptopp-cmake](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake) for [cryptopp](https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp) in my `CMakeLists.txt` file, since **Cryptopp** doesn't have a `CMakeLists.txt` file in its default project repository. My `CMakeLists.txt` has this **Cryptopp** related content:

```
# Include usage of external projects
include(FetchContent)

# Get the cryptopp CMakeLists.txt file for cryptopp package
set(CRYPTOPP_CMAKE "cryptopp-cmake")
FetchContent_Declare(
        ${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE}
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake
        GIT_TAG         CRYPTOPP_8_2_0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE})
if(NOT ${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE}_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE})
endif()


# Get the cryptopp package
set(CRYPTOPP "cryptopp")
FetchContent_Declare(
        ${CRYPTOPP}
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp
        GIT_TAG         CRYPTOPP_8_2_0
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(${CRYPTOPP})
if(NOT ${CRYPTOPP}_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(${CRYPTOPP})
endif()

# !!! IMORTANT !!! before using add_subdirectory(), include_directories() and set(CRYPTOPP_LIB....) commands.
file(COPY ${${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE}_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt DESTINATION ${${CRYPTOPP}_SOURCE_DIR})
add_subdirectory(${${CRYPTOPP}_SOURCE_DIR} ${${CRYPTOPP}_BINARY_DIR})
include_directories(${${CRYPTOPP}_SOURCE_DIR})
set(CRYPTOPP_LIB ${${CRYPTOPP}_BINARY_DIR}/libcryptopp.so)

# Link the project libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries(my_project PRIVATE
        ${CRYPTOPP_LIB}
)
```

When I let it run in **CLion** the `CMakeLists.txt` gets copied as it should but I get the error

```
No rule to make target '_deps/cryptopp-build/libcryptopp.so', needed by '../my_project/bin/my_project'.  Stop.
```

The `libcryptopp.so` file is not being generated on the first run despite of the successfully copied `CMakeLists.txt` and unfortunately, I need to use the "rebuild project" option in *CLion* for `libcryptopp.so` to be generated and populate the `${CRYPTOPP_LIB}` variable.

Is the a way to make **Cryptopp's** `CMakeLists.txt` file effect my build on the first run and generate the `libcryptopp.so` file?

Comment: You might consider filling out an issue on GitHub so the author (who is an active community [contributor](https://stackoverflow.com/users/608639/jww?tab=profile)) may provide insight and/or a fix.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a project creates a library with `add_library`, then link with that library using the **target** name. Do not use the library **file** in that case.

According to the cryptopp project's [CMakeLists.txt](https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake/blob/master/CMakeLists.txt#L962), the name of the library target is `cryptopp-shared`, so just link with it:

```
target_link_libraries(hmmenc-client PRIVATE cryptopp-shared)
```

#### Detailed explanations

You link your executable with a library file which is generated. So you need to be sure, that generation of this file is performed **before** the linking of your executable.

In CMake order between actions is specified by **dependency** between the **targets**. So your executable should be specified as **dependent** from the library as a **target**. In CMake a dependency between targets is specified by `add_dependencies()` command.

However, CMake provides a convenient way for link with a library and specifying the dependency at the same time. When you link with a library **target** (created by `add_library`):

1. CMake knows which library file corresponds to that library target, so it uses that file for actual linking.
2. CMake automatically adjust dependency between the executable target and the library target.

Comment: I've been walking thorough this CMakeLists.txt file multiple times and somehow I've managed to miss the part with `cryptopp-shared`.

Answer (score 1):

**Update:** This flow needs to be updated if using `cryptopp-cmake` above release version `CRYPTOPP_8_6_0`, it won't work as is anymore.

I ended up using this setting under Linux:

```
# Include usage of external projects
include(FetchContent)

############################################################################################
# Get the CryptoPP CMakeLists.txt File for CryptoPP Package GIT_TAG Must be the Same
############################################################################################
message(CHECK_START "Fetching CryptoPP-CMAKE")
set(CRYPTOPP_CMAKE "cryptopp-cmake")
set(CRYPTOPP_GIT_TAG "CRYPTOPP_8_2_0")
FetchContent_Declare(
        ${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE}
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake
        GIT_TAG         ${CRYPTOPP_GIT_TAG}
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE})
if(NOT ${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE}_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE})
endif()


############################################################################################
# Get the CryptoPP Package
############################################################################################
message(CHECK_START "Fetching CryptoPP")
set(CRYPTOPP "cryptopp")
FetchContent_Declare(
        ${CRYPTOPP}
        GIT_REPOSITORY  https://github.com/weidai11/cryptopp
        GIT_TAG         ${CRYPTOPP_GIT_TAG}
)

FetchContent_GetProperties(${CRYPTOPP})
if(NOT ${CRYPTOPP}_POPULATED)
    FetchContent_Populate(${CRYPTOPP})
    # !!! IMPORTANT !!!
    # Copy the CMakeLists.txt file from https://github.com/noloader/cryptopp-cmake with same TAG CRYPTOPP repository into ${${CRYPTOPP}_SOURCE_DIR}
    # before using add_subdirectory(), include_directories() and set(CRYPTOPP_LIB....) commands, until the a proper COPY command was implemented.
    file(COPY ${${CRYPTOPP_CMAKE}_SOURCE_DIR}/CMakeLists.txt DESTINATION ${${CRYPTOPP}_SOURCE_DIR})
    add_subdirectory(${${CRYPTOPP}_SOURCE_DIR} ${${CRYPTOPP}_BINARY_DIR})
endif()
include_directories(${${CRYPTOPP}_SOURCE_DIR})

# Set Cryptopp library properties every time after the first population
if(${CRYPTOPP}_POPULATED)
    # Build shared or static library
    set(BUILD_SHARED_CRYPTOPP_OLD ${BUILD_SHARED})
    set(BUILD_SHARED ON CACHE INTERNAL "Build CryptoPP SHARED libraries")
    message("Build CryptoPP shared lib is set to: ${BUILD_SHARED}")
    if(${BUILD_SHARED} STREQUAL "ON")
        set(CRYPTOPP "cryptopp-shared")
        else ()
            set(CRYPTOPP "cryptopp-static")
    endif()
    set(BUILD_SHARED ${BUILD_SHARED_CRYPTOPP_OLD} CACHE BOOL "Type of libraries to build" FORCE)
endif()

# Link the project libraries to the executable
target_link_libraries(my_project PRIVATE
        ${CRYPTOPP}
)
```